# getDownloadURL returns null when uploadTask is complete but uploads image to storage

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

The image I am trying to upload to storage is successful, however when I want to use that image that was uploaded to store the URL into the database, it returns null for some reason.

```
Future<String> _uploadPic(String docRef, File file) {
FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
auth.currentUser().then((userID) async{
  StorageReference reference = _storage.ref().child(userID).child(docRef);
  StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(file);
  String downloadURL = (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL().toString();

  return downloadURL;
});

}
```

Log:

```
I/flutter (17507): debug: the uri is: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<dynamic> _uploadPic(String docRef, File file) {

    FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

    // you need to return the result...
    return auth.currentUser().then((userID) async {
      StorageReference reference = _storage.ref().child(userID).child(docRef);
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(file);
      return (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    });

}
```

Comment: This seemed to work, only now that I am not getting the value of the download URL, I am getting the instance of the object, and not the value. I/flutter ( 9150): debug: the uri is: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'   Edit: Nevermind, I got it working by removing the toString() function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `getDownloadURL()` method returns a `Future`. So if you call `toString()` on that, you get the string representation of the future, and not a download URL. Instead you'll want to wait for the `getDownloadURL()` future to also complete, and **that** will give you the URL.

```
String downloadURL = (await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
```